# Linear Temporal Logic - Nested U(ntil) formulas

Tags: logic

I have trouble understanding nested Until Operators in Linear Temporal Logic.

Applying the following sentence: (Xp) U q

Assuming there exists a Kripke Structure with start state s0, does this mean: q has to hold in s0 and Xp has to hold in s1?

If so, the validity of the sentence for a Kripke Structure would depend solely on q, as upon fulfilling y of (x U y), x doesn't need to hold anymore and it is also valid with y holds immediately (in this particular case in s0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s0\Vdash (\mathsf Xp)\mathsf Uq$ means that $\mathsf Xp$ will hold in all instances until $q$ does.

$$\exists t\forall s~.[(s0\leq s\lt t)\wedge(s\Vdash \mathsf Xp\wedge\neg q)\wedge (t\Vdash q)]$$

That is: $p$ will hold in the successive instant of all instances until $q$ does.

$$\exists t\forall s~.[(s0\leq s\lt t)\wedge(s\Vdash\neg q)\wedge(\mathrm S(s)\Vdash p)\wedge(t\Vdash q)]$$

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} ?&p&p&\cdots&p&?\\\hline\neg q&\neg q&\neg q&\cdots& q& ?\end{array}}$$

---

> If so, the validity of the sentence for a Kripke Structure would depend solely on q, as upon fulfilling y of (x U y), x doesn't need to hold anymore and it is also valid with y holds immediately (in this particular case in s0).

Yes, $s0\Vdash (\mathsf Xp)\mathsf U q$ will be satisfied by a frame where $q$ holds immediately ($s0\Vdash q$), whether or not $p$ holds in the subsequent instant.